# Laravel как в сервис провайдере получить доступ к Auth::user()

Tags: laravel, laravel5

Всем привет, подскажите кто знает, как в сервис провайдере получить доступ к Auth::user()

`public function register() {
    $this->app->singleton(Cart::class, function () {
            return new Cart(
                new HybridStorage(Auth::user(), 'cart'),
                new DynamicCost(new SimpleCost())
            );
        });
    }`

Auth::user() всегда null, или может есть другой вариант привязки интерфейса к имплементации.

Comment: проблема заключается в том, что сервис провайдер стартует раньше, чем пользователь. Попробуйте уйти в сторону middleware

Comment: А в middleware я могу создать сингилтон "$this->app->singleton()"?